# How to add variables taken from a previous activity to the SQLite table as columns in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have already known how to create a SQL table with specified columns.

But I got this question when new variables(like names) need to be added to an existing SQL table as columns. Please note this is for android studio.

Can you guys give some advice on this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ALTER TABLE function on your onUpgrade() method in the SQLiteHelper class, to do this.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // If you need to add a column
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN new_column INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
    }
}
```

You may refer this link for syntax [Alter Table](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

Besides, don't forget to increase the version number in the below code, which will be present in the constructor of the class which extends the SQLiteOpenHelper class.

```
super(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int newVersion)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see what you mean but I guess I did not express the problem quite right. Now I have created the mySQLiteHelp.JAVA, where it seems I have to define all the columns in this file. But what if I want to pass the variables(names) entered by user to this mySQLLiteHelp.JAVA file and set them as columns.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

it is not ideal way to keep altering table dynamically based on user input.  Instead create a flexible table that can store key value pair to solve this.

key can be the user entered variable(which you are trying to make a new column name) and value is the content you have to store.